# How to add a Horizontal BarGraph in Android platform?

Tags: android

Any one please help me to build a horizontal bar graph in my android platform

Comment: Have you tried something? Are you starting from zero? Give details please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use "aCharEngine".

[aChartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org/)

Comment: in that eChartEngine i saw many demo projects.please let me know which one is for BarGraph

Answer (score 1):

There are two very good library are available for graph generating in android **AchartEngine** and **AndroidPlot** libraries you can use one of them.